# VPN Disconnects when switch user by RDP

Tags: windows, vpn, rdp, pptp

I have the following problem.
I have a WS2012 with a PPPT VPN configured (Allows other users to use the connection). The problem is that I connect by RDP with a user, I connect the VPN and if I connect with another user also by RDP the VPN is disconnected, but if I re-enter with the first user the session is still open. How can I fix this?